# How to output text from a database to a textbox in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, textbox

I want to output text stored in a database to a Textbox in C#. How to output the text from a column named `FBIDS`?

[image: Screenshot of database]

Comment: Where is your code? Add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, there are many different ways to skin this cat.  This is not the only way.

The following is a simple demo that will walk you through the process using Entity Framework.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363040/An-Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-for-Absolute-B